# User Interface and code. How they communicate? Is it just an image and nothing to do with program code

Tags: c#, architecture, user-interface

Does UI interface is just an Image created by graphics tools?. I need to know that when a user interface created to read an textbox in c#.

When a text entered is it take values from keyboard by `Readline.console` method and displays on screen terminal or it display first to screen and reads from screen coordinates.

Got confusion with UI and C# code. Is UI nothing but image? Is it nothing doing with C# code.

Comment: Please don't cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019354/how-ui-and-c-sharp-code-work-together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There's a UI right there.  You can see it has both text and image elements.  Though, in the end it's all image.  The searchable, selectable, and copyable text you see me typing right now ends up being an image on your screen, though unlike the image above it's sent to your computer as text.  Your computer converts it from text to an image to put it on your screen.  My computer did the same to give me the image I added above.  I used the print screen button and paint to turn it into a file I could attach.

It is possible to write code that creates vivid, detailed images that come from nothing but text based code.  Usually, little image files, text data, and code are combined wisely to, in the end, make the one big image that fills your screen.

c# code very much has something to do with the UI.  The UI of a c# program is controlled by code.  What controls are shown, what state they're in, what happens when they are manipulated, are all determined by code.

If you're asking how to interact with a UI using c# code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500500/basic-gui-event-handling-questions-c-sharp) is a good place to start.  I suggest you read up on [model view controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to learn to seperate these responsibilities, the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to learn what an event really is, and the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) so you'll see why things shouldn't be connected willy nilly.  Just having done that before hand would have improved many of the UI's I've worked on over the years.

Comment: Is there a possiblity of creating Ui image using some tool and use that image, for example creating shutdown button image and using Mouse event, when i click on the image co-ordinate and recieving that powerbutton cordinates , run my shutdown code.

Comment: You can build a UI from a single image and decide what actions to take based on mouse position.  Most UI tools relieve you of this burden by giving you controls that you add to the UI.  The tool takes care of deciding what was clicked on and you just have to react to the events it causes.  But if you want to do it the other way [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565081/how-to-increase-area-of-touch-by-a-certain-percentage)